# How to dissect both "message" and "log.file.path" from filestream type with filebeat?

Tags: filebeat, elk

I would like to export to kibana data from message and log.file.path fields with dissect processor.
Is it possible ?
My pipeline is Filebeat => ElastickSearch => Kibana.

I succeded to export to kibana, "message" fields with one dissect under processor key in the filebeat.yml
But can't do with the 2 fields.

Here is what I am trying:

```
 processors:
 -if:
    equals:
        field: "message"
    then:
    - dissect:
        tokenizer: "[%{@timestamo}][%{level}] %{message}"
 -if:
    equals:
        field: "log.file.path"
    then:
    - dissect:
        tokenizer: "/%{?}/{?}/%{key1}_%{key2}"
        target_prefix:"filepath"
```